# User friendly message when a webmin module dies

Tags: exception, die, webmin

Is there a way to get the message logged the normal way but to stop the printing of the same message in the navigator whenever a Webmin module dies?

I have tried many possibilities but none of them works.  What have Webmin community think of?

[ edit ]
In fact, standard output of webmin script are logged, but when the script output in error, this standard output is printed at web browser.  I just want the webmin miniserver to print an error 500 message, which I could custom, not to print the content of the standard error, but only that script has failed.